# Issue in applying margin using angular "data-ng-style"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

There is `<li>` element in HTML that is calling a JS method "SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset" like this

```
<li class="holder-white title-holder" data-ng-style="{{SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset()}}" data-ng-click="getSiteAssetDetailByAssetId(asset.id,asset.assetId,asset.jobPlantId, asset.siteAssetId, asset.uniqueKey, asset.plantId,asset.siteAssetGuidId);">
```

Inside JS we defined that method like this:

```
$scope.SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset = SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset;
function SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset() {

    var isPPMJob = localStorage.getItem("IsPPMJob").toUpperCase();

    var shiftingAsset = $scope.addClassForShiftingAsset;

    if (isPPMJob == "FALSE") {
        return { "margin-right": "50px" };
    }
    else if (isPPMJob == "TRUE") {
        if (shiftingAsset == true || shiftingAsset == "true") 
        {
            return { "margin-right": "50px" };
        }
        else {
            return { "padding-right:": "15px" };
        }
    }
}
```

In outer If condition that states "**if (isPPMJob == "FALSE")**" margin is applying perfectly fine
But when condition become "**TRUE**" in "**else if (isPPMJob == "TRUE")**" it isn't applying margin.
However alerts in all statements are working. Only problem with applying margin.
I have also inspected the element and it was showing **data-ng-style="{"margin-right":"50px"}"** but on the view nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for that problem.
The problem was with HTML code we were using data-ng-style like this

```
data-ng-style="{{SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset()}}"
```

instead of this we have to use it like

```
data-ng-style="{'margin-right': SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset()}"
```

Then in JS controller just return value of margin i.e. "10px" , "50px",etc

```
function SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset() {

        var isPPMJob = localStorage.getItem("IsPPMJob").toUpperCase();

        var shiftingAsset = $scope.addClassForShiftingAsset;

        if (shiftingAsset == "false"){
                    //alert("abc");
             return "10px";
                    //return { "padding-right:": "15px" };
        }
        else{
            return "50px";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see issue with the margin, but with the padding. You are having a colon within the quotes.
return { "padding-right:": "15px" };